# jQuery SlideToggle Trigger Change

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I want to achieve something like this: [**http://community.invisionpower.com/forum/1-news-and-information/**](http://community.invisionpower.com/forum/1-news-and-information/) - when you hover on the topics, an arrow will appear at the right side and clicking it will show the summary and the arrow icon will change to a close icon.

So far, I have made this one: [**http://jsfiddle.net/hfq4U/**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfq4U/). What's done is that when I hover the title container, it shows the "Show Summary" (*through CSS*) and clicking it will toggle the summary.

My problem now is that I don't know what to put (*or the logic behind it*) so that when clicking the 'Show Summary', it will change to "Hide Summary" and will still remain there even if my mouse leave the title container. [**This link**](http://community.invisionpower.com/forum/1-news-and-information/) shows exactly what I want to achieve.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Btw, I don't want to use any plugin just for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code right.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        $('.summary').not($(this).prev()).slideUp();
        $(this).prev('.summary').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Change it too..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        var _currentext = $('.toggler').html();
        if(_currentext == "Show Summary") {
            $('.toggler').html("Hide Summary");
        } else {
            $('.toggler').html("Show Summary");
        }
        $('.summary').not($(this).prev()).slideUp();
        $(this).prev('.summary').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Hope it works fine for you..

Comment: It does change from "Show..." to "Hide..." but the "Hide Summary" text will disappear when my mouse leave on each article container. I want that the "Hide Summary" will remain in there until I hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<div class="articles">
    <h3>Article Title 1</h3>
    <div class="summary">
        This is the summary for Article 1.
    </div>
    <span class="static" style="display:none;">Show Summary</span>
    <span class="toggler">Show Summary</span>
</div>

<div class="articles">
    <h3>Article Title 2</h3>
    <div class="summary">
        This is the summary for Article 2.
    </div>
    <span class="static" style="display:none;">Show Summary</span>
    <span class="toggler">Show Summary</span>
</div>

<div class="articles">
    <h3>Article Title 3</h3>
    <div class="summary">
        This is the summary for Article 3.
    </div>
    <span class="static" style="display:none;">Show Summary</span>
    <span class="toggler">Show Summary</span>
</div>

<div class="articles">
    <h3>Article Title 4</h3>
    <div class="summary">
        This is the summary for Article a.
    </div>
    <span class="static" style="display:none;">Show Summary</span>
    <span class="toggler">Show Summary</span>
</div>

<div class="articles">
    <h3>Article Title 5</h3>
    <div class="summary">
        This is the summary for Article 5.
    </div>
    <span class="static" style="display:none;">Show Summary</span>
    <span class="toggler">Show Summary</span>
</div>
```

Your jQUery..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        var _currentext = $('.toggler').html();
        if(_currentext == "Show Summary") {
            $('.toggler').html("Hide Summary");

            $('.static').hide();       
        } else {
            $('.toggler').html("Show Summary");
            $('.static').html("Hide Summary");
             $('.static').show();            
        }

        $('.summary').not($(this).prev()).slideUp();
        $(this).prev('.summary').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Text will appear below the "Articile Title". Make placement with your CSS now.